# confluent: Hdfs sink to avro format, but while reading the avro file in hive my time is 5:30 hours ahead of "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata"

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

My HDFS-Sink connection:

```
{
  "name":"hdfs-sink1",
  "config":{
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":"3",
    "topics":"mysql-prod-registrations-",
    "hadoop.conf.dir":"/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf",
    "hadoop.home":"/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client",
    "hdfs.url":"hdfs://HACluster:8020",
    "topics.dir":"/topics",
    "logs.dir":"/logs",
    "flush.size":"100",
    "rotate.interval.ms":"60000",
    "format.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroFormat",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
    "partition.duration.ms":"1800000",
    "path.format":"'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH/",
    "locale":"kor",
    "timezone":"Asia/Kolkata"
  }
}
```

But while reading in hive i am 5:30 hours ahead of timezone":"Asia/Kolkata". How to get the timestamp value in indian time zone?

**Connection was running fine for two days but iam getting error as below now:**

```
 ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink1-2} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.open(HdfsSinkTask.java:133)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.openPartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:612)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.access$1100(WorkerSinkTask.java:69)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask$HandleRebalance.onPartitionsAssigned(WorkerSinkTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:283)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:422)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:352)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:337)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:343)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1218)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1181)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:444)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:317)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2018-12-14 12:22:39,670] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink1-2} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Asia/Kolkata` is `+05:30` after before UTC, so that makes some sense... And the `timezone` config only applies to the `path.format` values, not internal values of your Kafka records.

I'm not sure which tool you are using to query with, but it might be a problem there because I have had some tools assume the data is only written in UTC time, then the tool will "shift" and "display" a formatted local timestamp... Therefore, I would suggest making the HDFS sink connector actually write in UTC time, then let your SQL tools and operating system handle the actual TZ conversions themselves.

Comment: my above connection started throwing error as mentioned above. It was working fine for sometime and able to get data in HDFS

Comment: I am not sure. I would suggest enabling TRACE logging in the `connect-log4j.properties` file, then getting the output, and pasting it as a Github issue on the HDFS connector project

Comment: still getting same ERROR as Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178). This was working fine actually and started throwing error now. iam confused and unable to trace what is the ISSUE

Comment: I see that error, but the TRACE logging is for diagnostic purposes, not a fix for your problem, which I am not sure about